# Unable to migrate to Androidx

Tags: react-native

I have search around but could not find any solution for my case.

I wanted to migrate my project to androidx and got following error:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehNkv.png)

Apparently, I am using com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2. However, the migrate tool detected my old gradle.

Does anyone have solution for this?
Thanks

Solution for me:

`Delete my node_modules then install it again.
 Run npx jetifier`

I was able to migrate after that.

Thank you.

Comment: Run `gradlew clean` in android folder

Comment: Ran gradlew clean, but it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Add these 2 lines to android/gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

and then run `npx jetifier`

Comment: ran `npx jetifier` did help but still, migrate to androidx is still complain about gradle:3.2.0